# How to parse JSON into HTML Menu in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, drop-down-menu

I have a website that I've been working on, updating each time I find a better way of doing things. Right know I've started using DataTables, but some of the HTML tables that I have are too large and time out.

To fix this I'm trying to convert to using server-side processing, which requires JSON. I've never used JSON so I'm learning as I go. What I'm trying to do first is convert the menu to JSON. Only the menu has several levels and I can't seem to get anything to work.

Here's what I've got so far:

TestFile: with the JSON I'm trying to convert:

```
{"NavMenu":"ul","class":"clearfix","id":"menu","html":[
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"default.aspx","html":"Home"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"MaterialTracking.php","html":"Material Tracking"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"OPR Reports.php","html":"OPR Reports"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"CAFII Reports"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"ENG Reports"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"Admin"}]}
]}
```

PHP file that I'm using to do the converting with a modified script that I found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_http.asp)

```
<div id="id1"></div>
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "TestFile.txt";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            alert('Made it to a good file');
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            myfunction(myarr);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert('Right before the function');
    function myFunction(arr)
    {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        alert('Made it into the function');
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            out += '<' + arr[i].NavMenu + '>';
            for (a = 0; arr[i].html.length; a++)
            {
                out += '<' + arr[i].html[a].NavMenu + ' href="' + arr[i].html[a].href + '">' + arr[i].html[a].html + '</' + arr[i].html[a].NavMenu + '>';
            }
            out += '</' + arr[i].NavMenu + '><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = out;
    }
</script>
```

I got the JSON from a converter I found [here](http://json2html.com/) under the "Builder" tab.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what.

Also if this isn't the best way to convert these tables into JSON for server side processing let me know that too so I can move on to something that will be more productive. I just have a bunch of reports that are too large to handle client side.

**EDIT**

I've changed the I'm doing things to try and only pull the tables back using JSON based on the recommendation below. However, I only get a blank screen with this:

```
<?php
/* Enter the column names which you want you retrieve
   I use a table in my DB to hold all column names for the several 
   tables that I will pull back.   
 */
$Page = '';
if (isset($_GET['PageName']))
{
    //echo "<br>Page = Get<br>";
    $Page = $_GET['PageName'];
}
elseif (isset($_POST['PageName']))
{
    //echo "<br>Page = Post<br>";
    $Page = $_POST['PageName'];
}

$hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = '$Page' order by Id";
$getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$CountHeadings = count($rHeadings);
//print_r($hsql);
$tsqlHeadings = '';
for ($row = 0; $row < $CountHeadings; $row++)
{
    $headings[$row] = $rHeadings[$row]["Headings"];
    $tsqlHeadings = $tsqlHeadings . "[" . $headings[$row] . '],';
}

$aColumns = $headings; //array( 'engine', 'browser', 'platform', 'version', 'grade' );

/* Indexed column (Ex: id or employee_id etc.) */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = $Page;
include 'DBConn.php';

/*
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}

/*
 * MySQL connection
 * I don't use MySQL so I had to convert that to what I do use PDO SqlSrv
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}


/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".quote( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".quote($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
$rResult = $conn->query($sQuery);// or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = $conn->query($sQuery);// or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = $conn->query($sQuery);// or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var table=$('#datatable').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "ajax-handler.php",
                    pagingType: "bootstrap_full_number",
                    "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
                    "language": {
                        "lengthMenu": "",
                        "zeroRecords": "No Messages!",
                        "infoEmpty": "Empty"
                    }
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my connection info from DBConn.php:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;database=$dbname", $username,$password);
//print_r($conn);
//set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

**EDIT 2**

I have gotten it to kind of work. I have based my code on what Sarath has below in his answer. I also have a page where I'm trying what Press has in his answer. For both I get something that looks like this as the output:

Sarath:

```
{"iTotalRecords":{"":280},"iTotalDisplayRecords":false,"aaData":[[1,"TableUpdates","Id"],[2,"TableUpdates","TableName"],[3,"TableUpdates","UpdateDate"],[1,"ApprovedProjects","Id"],[2,"ApprovedProjects","Company"],[3,"ApprovedProjects","State"],[4,"ApprovedProjects","Project"],[5,"ApprovedProjects","SubProject"],[6,"ApprovedProjects","Division"],[7,"ApprovedProjects","PlantNum"],[8,"ApprovedProjects","Exchange"],[9,"ApprovedProjects","DeptNum"],[10,"ApprovedProjects","ClassOfPlant"],[11,"ApprovedProjects","StatusCode"],[12,"ApprovedProjects","JustCode"],[13,"ApprovedProjects","Description"],[14,"ApprovedProjects","InfProjType"],
```

Press:

```
{"NavMenu":"ul","class":"clearfix","id":"menu","html":[ {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"default.aspx","html":"Home"}]}, {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"MaterialTracking.php","html":"Material Tracking"}]}, {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"OPR Reports.php","html":"OPR Reports"}]}, {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"CAFII Reports"}]}, {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"ENG Reports"}]}, {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"Admin"}]} ]}
```

How do I turn the first one into a table and second one into a menu?

Comment: Can you give a bit more info? Are you trying to build up and render the menu client side from a json you get from the server? Or do you have to package an existing (static?) menu into a json file to send to the server?

Comment: @Shilly I'm trying to build up and render a menu client side from a json I get from the server. I think that I've figured out how to convert everything into json on the server, I just don't know how to display it on the client.

Comment: Does your main menu actually change depending on the viewed report? I've been down the same road concerning a reporting website and in the end we settled for a static html file containing the report menu and then generate each report dynamically since the main navigation never changed. You could look into some templating system if it does have to be dynamic. Also, if All those links are `<a>` tags inside a `<li>`, you can simplify your json structure alot. Anyways, the good people below have found the bug in your code. :)

Comment: @Shilly The menu is basically static. It only changes based on who is logged in. There are 2 different versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need parse json and use in DataTable simply use datatable server side script. Just replace column names, indexed column, database connection settings. Don't change anything.

**Ajax-handler.php :**

```
/* Enter the column name which you want you retrieve   
 */
$aColumns = array( 'engine', 'browser', 'platform', 'version', 'grade' );

/* Indexed column (Ex: id or employee_id etc.) */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "ajax";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "";
$gaSql['password']   = "";
$gaSql['db']         = "";
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";



/*
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}


/*
 * MySQL connection
 */
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}


/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

**Datatable funtion using jQuery :**

```
var table=$('#datatable').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "ajax-handler.php",
        pagingType: "bootstrap_full_number",
        "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "",
            "zeroRecords": "No Messages!",
            "infoEmpty": "Empty"
        }
    });
```

I have made few changes for PDO Sqlserver
**Change:**

```html
<?php
/* Enter the column names which you want you retrieve
   I use a table in my DB to hold all column names for the several 
   tables that I will pull back.   
 */
 

 
$Page = '';
if (isset($_GET['PageName']))
{
    //echo "<br>Page = Get<br>";
    $Page = $_GET['PageName'];
}
elseif (isset($_POST['PageName']))
{
    //echo "<br>Page = Post<br>";
    $Page = $_POST['PageName'];
}

$hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = '$Page' order by Id";
$getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$CountHeadings = count($rHeadings);
//print_r($hsql);
$tsqlHeadings = '';
for ($row = 0; $row < $CountHeadings; $row++)
{
    $headings[$row] = $rHeadings[$row]["Headings"];
    $tsqlHeadings = $tsqlHeadings . "[" . $headings[$row] . '],';
}

$aColumns = $headings; //array( 'engine', 'browser', 'platform', 'version', 'grade' );

/* Indexed column (Ex: id or employee_id etc.) */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = $Page;
include 'DBConn.php';

/*
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}

 /* DATABASE CONNECTION */
$serverName = "serverName\instanceName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".quote( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".quote($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT count($sIndexColumn) over() as Row_Count ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";

$rResult = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sQuery );
if( $rResult === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

/* Data set length after filtering */
$iFilteredTotal = sqlsrv_num_rows( $rResult );

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "SELECT COUNT($sIndexColumn)
    FROM $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sQuery );
$aResultTotal = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResultTotal, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResult,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>  
    </head>
    <body>
 
 <table id="datatable">
  <thead>
   <!-- Number of columns should be same as $aColumns -->
  </thead>
 </table>
        <script>
            var table=$('#datatable').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "ajax-handler.php",
                    pagingType: "bootstrap_full_number",
                    "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
                    "language": {
                        "lengthMenu": "",
                        "zeroRecords": "No Messages!",
                        "infoEmpty": "Empty"
                    }
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah you can use sql server also. But you have to use PDO instead. If you want I can update the answer.

Comment: That would be great. I am already using PDO for sqlsrv, but not sure how to convert from the mySql functions you have in your answer.

Comment: You have change the mysql functions to PDO and give array in a while loop.

Comment: I think I might be able to do the switch from MySql functions to PDO, but what array in what while loop?

Comment: Yeah there is a while loop in the script below.Please take look.

Comment: Accept the answer it may help other users.

Comment: I have added more info to my question. I updated your script with what I think would be the correct functions from PDO and sqlsrv. Could you look at it and see where I've gone wrong, I am getting a black screen when running it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127309/discussion-between-sarath-kumar-and-mike).

Comment: The problem is in query. Actually there no SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in SQL Server. Do one thing echo **$sQuery** and run the query in sql server. Once you got the right result then check datatable it might work. Please change query.

Comment: I got it working, I think. Using a small table I get 280 rows. Now I'm to the point where it's in the `//Output` I get an error saying ` Notice: Undefined index: sEcho`. where is this supposed to be coming from and what is it?

Comment: There are many parameters passed through the url by default. sEcho is one of them. The url might like this: https://example.com/ajax-handler.php?sEcho=2&iColumns=9&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=960&iDisplayLength=10 etc... While request raised by DataTable.

Comment: There isn't anything being sent through `$_GET` that I didn't put there and i didn't add a sEcho. I have a PageName set in `$_GET`. I ran a `print_R($_GET);` and this is what was returned: `Array ( [PageName] => TableHeadings )`

Comment: Continue in chat.

Comment: That got me through the code. But the output is not a table. How to I make it a table?

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to rewrite your function to generate the nav for you.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z130obt9/2/)

```js
var menuJson = {"NavMenu":"ul","class":"clearfix","id":"menu","html":[
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"default.aspx","html":"Home"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"MaterialTracking.php","html":"Material Tracking"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"OPR Reports.php","html":"OPR Reports"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"CAFII Reports"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"ENG Reports"}]},
    {"NavMenu":"li","html":[{"NavMenu":"a","href":"#","html":"Admin"}]}
]}, menu = null;

function generateMenu(_menu) {
  var menu = null,
    item = null;
  menu = '<' + _menu.NavMenu + ' class="' + _menu.class + '" id="' + _menu.id + '">';
  for (var i = 0; i < _menu.html.length; i++) {
    item = _menu.html[i];
    menu += '<' + item.NavMenu + '>';
    menu += '<' + item.html[0].NavMenu + ' href="' + item.html[0].href + '">' + item.html[0].html + '</' + item.html[0].NavMenu + '>';
    menu += '</' + item.NavMenu + '>';
  }
  menu += '</' + menu.NavMenu + '>';
  return menu;
}

menu = generateMenu(menuJson);

document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML = menu;
```

```html
<div id="id1">

</div>
```

The function I wrote doesn't check for any other elements inside the `html` block of each of your nav(`li`) items. However, it does get the job done nicely.

As for the issue with your function I think the issue lies with `arr[i].html[a].href` more specifically the `.html[a].href`. Since `a` increments for each nav item(`li`) it'll try and look for an index that doesn't exist in the array. Instead of `html[a].href` try `html[0].href`.

Comment: I'm pulling the Menu from a separate file, how would I incorporate that into what you have shown? I've tried `<?php $FileInclude = include 'TestFile.txt'; ?> var menuJson = FileInclude;` this doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: @Mike you would get the file the same way you did in your original question with the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Okay, I've re-added the XMLHttpRequest. Now I get an output, but it's not a menu. It looks like the json is being printed to the screen as text.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function myFunction(arr)
{
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.html.length; i++)
    {
        out += '<' + arr.html[i].NavMenu + '>';
     for (a = 0; a < arr.html[i].html.length; a++)
        {

            out += '<' + arr.html[i].html[a].NavMenu + ' href="' + arr.html[i].html[a].href + '">' + arr.html[i].html[a].html + '</' +arr.html[i].html[a].NavMenu + '>';
        }

        out += '</' + arr.html[i].NavMenu + '><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = out;
}
```

works, your error is that you are iterating ot arr instead of html element mostly.